# impulses in domain region and something in frequency region

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am studying about the fourier series and fourier transform.

and I am suffering to deal with the picture that I will show you

[image]

I am sure that the signal upper in the picture has periodicity and

I know that some periodic continous signals can be represented by impulses

(because of fourire series)

but I don't know why those signals with same magnitude.

So my question is that

why the signals in lower picture is same value at P, 2P, 3P ?

and How can I get those signals( impulses which have same value ) from the

upper circle?

Thank you for answers in advanced.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE ! In its present form, it is quite impossible to figure out what you are talking about. For instance, what is the relation between these two graphs, or what is the subject in this textbook ? Please read [advices and policy](http://math.stackexchange.com/help) of this website and edit your question.

Comment: Oh, okay, I will do for that now! Thank you for comment :D